# What does the saber flash mean?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've noticed a difference in fighting with a saber since the beta, it now flashes occasionally. Anyone know what this means? I'm not sure if it's a parry/block or critical?

The flash is a bright blue, flash emanating from the saber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience from level 1-10, melee weapons glow strongly in their color during a critical hit.  You might call it a flash.

This is very easy to observe with the Consular's starting force/melee attack.

---

A blindingly blue flash, along with lensflare on your eyes means that you have avoided an attack and should now use your Jedi Knight's Riposte ability.  You will see the flash even when you lack the focus to use this ability.

Comment: Ah hah, I thought it was something like that. Thanks!